# Inner Join MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, select, join, where-clause

Lets presume i have a database called db

I have a table with the following column headers

```
DateAndTime | Millitm | TagIndex | Val | Status | Marker | NumIndex
```

Lets call this table A

I have another table with columns

```
L_Index | L_Name | WritePos
```

Lets call this table B

I initially had the query format

```
SELECT * FROM db.A WHERE DateAndTime = (SELECT min(DateAndTime) FROM db.A)
INNER JOIN db.b 
ON a.Val = b.L_Index
```

I get a syntax error here when doing this.

I am used to SQL and am having to change to MySQL so I'm getting used to syntax changes here but am I missing something stupid here?

Kind Regards.

Jordan

Comment: shouldn't you move the `where` clause to the end?

Comment: If you try this in *any* SQL database it will be wrong. I asume you mean that you are used to SQL *Server* (please note: "SQL" stands for *Structured Query Language*, and "SQL Server" is *just one* of many database systems that use SQL)

Comment: Hi Barranka, I indeed meant to say SQL Server instead of just SQL :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is worng. try this:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM db.A INNER JOIN db.b ON a.Val = b.L_Index
 WHERE A.DateAndTime = (SELECT min(A.DateAndTime) FROM db.A)
```

Comment: Hi anikit, I will try this at work tomorrow! thank you in advanced if this works! :D